# App Fetching slowly large number of data from firebase react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native

```
async function getData(ret) {

var list = [];

const b = await firebase.database().ref('tesco').limitToFirst(20).on('value',function (snapshot) {

    snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
    list.push(childSnapshot.val())
```

I have to push data from firebase , to Array. It takes alot of time and i have to refresh App to see data on Screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put the `list` or return of `getData()` in a state, so every time it has new value the component will refreshed automatically